# Validate custom xml file during bbuild and fail the build if the validation failed

Tags: xml, eclipse, build, makefile

I have couple of XML files that I want to validate during build.
I want to make sure the build will fail if the XMLs validation failed.
I am using eclipse and I tried use its validation tool but it does not fail the build (in addition to the face that it is not perfect).
Is there some recommended line to add to the configuration or some other external free tool to add to the makefile?
I only need simple syntax validation, no DTD or schema checks.
I searched the web through and through, will thank you for any lead.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlwf from the expat project can do simple well-formed-ness checking.
xmllint from libxml2 can do other correctness checking.

I believe both of them will fail with an error return when the document fails the tests which should allow you to fail the make target in question.